# How do I add synonyms to a switch statement in Java?

Tags: java, synonym

I have the function below and I want to add synonyms to each case for example case "north" could also be "up", case "east" could be right etc. Since all the cases fall into the same try/catch statement I wasn't sure how I could do that for each specific case. Appreciate any help! Thanks

```
public void changeRoom(boolean isValidInput, String[] input, int attemptCount) {
        while (isValidInput) {
            switch (input[1]) {
                case "north":
                case "east":
                case "south":
                case "west":
                    try {
                        if (world.getCurrentRoom().roomExits.containsKey(input[1])) {
                            player.setMostRecentExit(input[1]);
                            world.setCurrentRoom(world.getCurrentRoom().roomExits.get(input[1]));
                            isValidInput = false;
                            if (isSound) {
                                walkEffect.playSoundEffect();
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(1800);
                            narrateRooms(world.getCurrentRoom().getDescription());
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                default:
                    System.out.println("You hit a wall. Try again: ");
                    System.out.print(">>>");
                    attemptCount++;
                    if (attemptCount >= 2) {
                        System.out.println();
                        openMap();
                        System.out.println("Where would you like to go? ");
                        System.out.print(">>>");
                    }
                    input = scanner.nextLine().strip().toLowerCase().split(" ");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Same mechanism, or likely better, run the input through some sort of normalizer. Noting that "up" only works for north in a 2d world.

Comment: You could define a map of synonyms, e.g. `Map.of("up", "north", "right", "east" /* etc */)`, and then switch on e.g. `map.getOrDefault(input[1].toLowerCase(), input[1].toLowerCase())` instead

Answer (score 1):

Just list those cases like that:

```
switch (input[1]) {
            case "north": case "up":
            case "east": case "right":
            case "south": case "down":
            case "west": case "left":
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried but did not work. I am trying to understand how to normalize that but don't have enough experience to know how to do it on my own

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I might add this works due to the lack of a break statement between the first string and its alias, which has to be in front of each case in order to differentiate a case from anothe (example: `case "north": case "up": [...] break;`).

Comment: Thanks Maurizio! I have a break statement inside the try/catch block and I did try to add the  semi-colons between each case like below but still doesn't work. Do I need the break statement outside the try/catch block?
                case "north": case "up":
                case "east": case "right":
                case "south": case "down":
                case "west": case "left":

Comment: I'm away from my computer and can't confirm it, so I might be saying something wrong, but... It does indeed seem like the try block has a scope of its own, especially when there's a thrown exception and the break isn't executed, which would make me say yes, I'd try using the break outside of that scope but still inside the aliased cases. Unfortunately, it's been a long time since I read the Java standard, so I have no clear memory of the behaviour of the break inside the try construct. In any case, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? The default block is executed or what?

Comment: I really appreciate your help Maurizio! I was able to normalize the input.

Comment: @MaurizioCarcassona you are absolutely right, thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to normalize the input by creating the function below. Thanks, everybody!

```
public String normalizeText(String input) {
    List<String> northOptions = Arrays.asList("north", "up");
    List<String> southOptions = Arrays.asList("south", "down");
    List<String> eastOptions = Arrays.asList("east", "right");
    List<String> westOptions = Arrays.asList("west", "left");
    if (northOptions.contains(input.toLowerCase())) {
        return "north";
    }
    if (southOptions.contains(input.toLowerCase())) {
        return "south";
    }
    if (eastOptions.contains(input.toLowerCase())) {
        return "east";
    }
    if (westOptions.contains(input.toLowerCase())) {
        return "west";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I see you went the indirect way - the one I would've taken as well :) good job!